# Настройка JMeter при использовании Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, jmeter, kerberos, ntlm

Есть интрасеть, в которой находятся все компьютеры предприятия и QA-зона. В интернет все компьютеры интрасети выходят через прокси, в правилах указаны адреса (маски всех адресов, находящихся внутри интрасети), доступ к которым осуществляется не через прокси.

Во всей сети используется Active Directory, в том числе и авторизация на порталах SharePoint в зоне QA.

Нужно с помощью JMeter провести нагрузочное тестирование портала, который размещен в QA-зоне.

Пытался настраивать JMeter, обращался за адресами KDC, чтобы указать их в настройках, ничего не помогало.

Наилучший результат: получалось собирать данные с сайтов, находящихся вне интрасети, с сайтов внутри интрасети получать данные было невозможно.

В браузере выскакивал диалог авторизации, но действительные данные не принимались.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы авторизоваться в SharePoint вам нужно:

1. Вступить в связь с администратором SharePoint и узнать детали аутентификации ([NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) это или [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)))
2. Если это Kerberos- настроить параметры Kerberos в файле [*krb5.conf*](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/krb5.conf) (находится в папке "bin")

   - Возможно потребуется дополнительно произвести конфигурацию в файле [*jaas.conf*](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/jaas.conf)
3. Добавить [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) и указать там путь к Sharepoint, имя пользователя, пароль, домен, [realm](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2015/10/21/domain-to-kerberos-realm-mapping/), и убедиться что выбран механизм `KERBEROS` для Kerberos или `DIGEST` для NTLM

Примеры конфигурации JMeter для обхода NTLM / Kerberos можно посмотреть в статье [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)